# Can't Save PIL Image From Shell Command (PHP)

Tags: php, python, python-imaging-library

I have a pretty simple python script that creates an image, writes some text, and finally outputs to a file.  Running the script from terminal via ssh works fine and outputs the image as expected.  However, if I attempt to run the command via php everything works up until I run the img.save() function.

The folder I am writing to has global write permissions, so I'm not sure what the hangup could be.

Suggestions?

PYTHON:

```
from PIL import Image
background = Image.new('RGB', (50, 50), 'black')
print 'img created'
background.save('test.png')
print 'img saved'
```

PHP:

```
$execStr = "python imgScript.py";
exec($execStr,$output,$message);
print_r($output);
//output// Array ( [0] => img created )
```

Comment: Try an absolute path

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov will you marry me?   Worked perfect.  Thank you.

Comment: posted this as answer

Comment: Some time back PIL got forked into Pillow which I understand is better https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an absolute path. Like this:

```
background.save('/path/to/test/test.png')
```

or even this:

```
import os
background.save(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'test.png'))
```

This will save file in the same directory as your script